# Visual proof of Gauss Theorem?

Tags: visualization, interactive-proofs

I saw some proofs about [Gauss Theorem here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615231/slick-proof-of-gauss-theorem) but I could not understand everything about it.

Is it possible to have a visual proof of Gauss Theorem, as it can be very interesting to understand and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface integral of vectorial quantity is the net flux & Divergence of vectorial quantity is total vectorial quantity produce or sink otherwords, total sources or sinks of vector quantity. So physically we can see,

> “Total vectorial quantity produce or sink inside closed surface throughout the volume is equal to net flex of this vectorial quantity across the volume boundary.”

Let’s consider, S is a closed surface such that no line parallel to co ordinate axes cuts it in more than two points. Thus, S is a double valued surface over its projection on the region D in XY plane. S be consist of 2 sub surfaces lower surface S1 & upper surface S2.

[image: gauss]

S1 : $z = f1 (x,y)$ consisting of points $(x,y,f1)$

S2 : $z = f2 (x,y)$ consisting of points $(x,y,f2)$

Now, assuming a vectorial quantity, $F = Fx i +Fy j +Fz k$

[image: proofPart1]

Total vector quantity produce or sink inside S throughout the volume V is

[image: proofPart2]

Taking a part,

[image: proofPart3]

Since Upper surface S2 where unit normal $η2$ makes an angle with Z axis then $η2.k=cosθ2$

Lower surface S1 where unit normal $η1$ makes an angle with Z axis then $η1.k=-cosθ1$

Thus, The projections are,
 $S2 : dxdy = cosθ2*dS2$ & $S1 : dxdy = -cosθ1*dS1$

[image: proofPart4]

Similarly,

[image: proofPart5]

Therefore,

[image: proofPart6]

QED.